# Add remove button to global messages

Tags: magento-1.9, global-messages

I want to add a delete icon to the global messages in Magento 1.9. But it seems there is no template file for these messages (or at least, I can't find it in my installation and on the internet). Is there a way (preferably not using JavaScript (or jQuery) to append a button) to add a delete button to the messages?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

override this **block**

`app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Messages.php`

**To local**

`app/code/local/Mage/Core/Block/Messages.php`

and do changes here.

Answer (score 3):

There is a free [extension for that](https://github.com/tzyganu/floating-message). It allows you to show the session messages as floating divs and adds a close button to them, or it can even close the messages after a number of seconds.

If you don't want an extension, you can rewrite the method `getGroupedHtml` from the class `Mage_Core_Block_Messages` and insert your button in there.

Comment: do you have any idea who's the developer of that module :)

Comment: you are wrong @QaisarSatti , he is `tzyganu ` much better developer than Marius :)

Comment: @BabyinMagento it is username `tzyganu` check the name `Marius Strajeru`